# How to pass variable to a input request in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and new to programming.
Can anyone tell me how I can code the following correctly?

```
name=raw_input("What is your name?  ")
age=raw_input(" How old are you",name)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
name = raw_input('What is your name? ')
age = raw_input('How old are you, %s? ' % name)
```

Or:

```
name = raw_input('What is your name? ')
age = raw_input('How old are you, {}? '.format(name))
```

The `raw_input` function can't receive more than 1 argument. We can overcome this problem by using string formatting (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for info on the different types of formatting).

Also, depending on what you want to do, you might also want to convert `age` into an integer. We can do this:

```
age = int(age)
```

but if the user entered something else, like `'foobar'`, then you'll get an error. You can bypass this using a `try/except` block, and using a `while` loop so you can loop until you get a valid number.

```
name = raw_input('What is your name? ')
while True:
    age = raw_input('How old are you, {}? '.format(name))
    try:
        age = int(age)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'You entered an invalid age. Please try again.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use type conversion. Anyway, the following code should do it:

```
name = str(raw_input('Enter your name:'))

string1 = 'Enter your age,' + name + ':'

age = int(raw_input(string1))
```

As you can see, i have the stored whatever i want to prompt into a string called string1 and then i have used it as the parameter to raw_input.

raw_input takes only one parameter. So, you can do it this way.

And i have used python 2.7 for this. If you are using

Comment: `raw_input` already returns a string - there's no need to convert that into a string again

Comment: sir, but it would be safe to do so. As if we don't put single quotes around the string then some times it does give an error.

Comment: `raw_input` never gives errors... (at least to my knowledge). It simply returns the string that the user inputted.

Comment: i am sorry sir. I was confusing it with input(). input gives an error and i have seen this myself. for strings we need to enclose it with single quotes.